# Convert multiple uploaded files to Base64 in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to convert uploaded files to base64 in order to upload them to an API in my Angular application

I have the following code which works well for single files, but if the user selects multiple files, I just get the first file several times, ie, the second and subsequent files aren't being converted to Base64.

What am I doing wrong?

```
onFileChanged(event) {

    var files = event.target.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {

        this.selectedFile = new SelectedFile();

        this.totalSize += files[i].size;
        var extension = files[i].name.split('.').pop();

        this.selectedFile.extension = (extension === files[i].name) ? '' : extension;
        this.selectedFile.name = files[i].name;
        this.selectedFile.size = files[i].size;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(files[i]);    
  };
}

handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
  var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
  this.base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
  this.selectedFile.file = btoa(binaryString);
  this.selectedFiles.push(this.selectedFile);
}
```

Comment: Is only the last selected file uploaded?

Comment: Only the first actually from what I can see

Comment: I believe the problem is that FileReader is asynchronous. Try using [FileReaderSync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReaderSync) instead. Now, you don't need to handle the `onload` event.